# ssh unix_listener: cannot bind to path

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to tunnel through a computer (HOST) to which I (justin) have ssh access to so that rsyncd has a secure connection for BackupPC.

The following is the ssh command (DumpPreUserCmd in BackupPC):

```
/usr/bin/ssh -4 -M -S stradella-socket -fN -l justin -L 58874:stradella.local:873 HOST -p PORT -vvv
```

ssh is able to connect and authenticate, but fails trying to bind to a socket (presumably permission denied). This is from the BackupPC log which shows the verbose ssh debug:

```
2019-04-23 21:00:06 Output from DumpPreUserCmd: debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
2019-04-23 21:00:06 Output from DumpPreUserCmd: Authenticated to HOST ([XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]:PORT).
2019-04-23 21:00:06 Output from DumpPreUserCmd: debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:58874 forwarded to remote address stradella.local:873
2019-04-23 21:00:06 Output from DumpPreUserCmd: debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
2019-04-23 21:00:06 Output from DumpPreUserCmd: debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 58874.
2019-04-23 21:00:06 Output from DumpPreUserCmd: debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
2019-04-23 21:00:06 Output from DumpPreUserCmd: debug3: fd 4 is O_NONBLOCK
2019-04-23 21:00:06 Output from DumpPreUserCmd: debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
2019-04-23 21:00:06 Output from DumpPreUserCmd: debug1: setting up multiplex master socket
2019-04-23 21:00:06 Output from DumpPreUserCmd: debug3: muxserver_listen: temporary control path stradella-socket.ksAS6rhpPSFtRqxW
2019-04-23 21:00:06 Output from DumpPreUserCmd: bind: Permission denied
2019-04-23 21:00:06 Output from DumpPreUserCmd: unix_listener: cannot bind to path: stradella-socket.ksAS6rhpPSFtRqxW
```

Comment: `stradella-socket` is not an absolute path. Do you know the directory the command runs in? Is the user running the command permitted to create a socket there? What if you used an absolute path? a socket in a directory with known and proper permissions, so you know for sure the command *can* create files there.

Comment: That's it. "/usr/bin/ssh -4 -M -S ~/.ssh/stradella-socket ..." fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my vscode, I had some pending docker containers point to the same ssh target. So I stop all of them and it works now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).